# Simplest and quickest rig to hack an LED Voltmeter for USB interface

Tags: usb, interface, voltmeter

I have a few LED Voltmeters that's almost identical to this:
[image]

I need to log fairly DC voltages for long spans. Sampling every few second or fractions of seconds or so. I know decoding the exact digits displayed is fairly straightforw89ard as this is a 7 segment LED display and the through hole pins are just asking to be soldered to. Since I'm interfacing it through USB to my PC, I know I can simply sample these 12 pins; serialize each pin as a bit into a WORD; send it through the USB; probably do that for a given cycle (for multiplexing); then have the software decode the raw signals and have the software do this every second or so (as I need it to be).

What's the simplest and quickest rig to do this? I'd rather have most of the work be on the software side. As I am more comfortable working with software; rather than go through learning how to work with another board.

It's also a good thing to be able to connect a few of these LED voltmeters onto the same USB port.

Comment: Just take an attiny and communicate via serial, much easier.

Comment: Is there a project page that you can point to? I'm still not that comfortable working with boards. I'm top-level and software on the left and low-level discrete and power on the right, with the middle need filling in with experience.

Comment: So with an ATtiny; it samples the pins; does that for a few cycles (for multiplexing); then decodes that to the binary numeric value; do that for the next digits and then serialize it through USB? Is that the gist of it? Because using USB raw, is from what I gather, is hard, this does sounds easier... Can I somehow modify the rig so it can take a few more voltmeter, using only one ATtiny?

Comment: A project page is still preferable.

Comment: Your idea may be a lot harder than you think. The display may well be multiplexed which makes picking off the signals a complex time dependent task.

Comment: @Trevor: NO! I can imagine it, so it's easy! Never underestimate the power of igamination.

Comment: @Trevor: Seriously, though, walk me through why it would be "A LOT" harder than I laid it to be. Be sure to pick on every little mistake in my argument.

Comment: The segments may not all be on in the static way you think they are. Rather, whatever is driving them may refresh one digit at a time, or one row of segments at a time, or any combination of the above. That means you would need to monitor two or more signals simultaneously to decode the data. It gets complicated fast. You would likely be quicker and easier grabbing the voltage data directly. Pick up a meter that is hooked and showing a voltage and wave it around in the air.. If the digits seems to be flashing..it is multiplexed.

Comment: It's a generic 3 digit seven segment display, to lower cost. I'm sure the order they're doing it would be common industry standard. It'll be easy to decode once I sample it properly...

Comment: Hmmm... I guess you're right... Sampling it IS the problem... Without knowing the exact time when the last cycle is through the whole matrix, it would be hard to determine.

Comment: How about if I hook it to a constant voltage, so the display is ALWAYS the same; a voltage where every digit is different. Then I sample about 10 times faster than the LED is refreshed (guesswork). Using the ATtiny I can look up the repeating bit-stream. Then I can establish the refresh rate -- when the last cycle is through the whole matrix. Then I can go ahead figuring out the order each LED segment is toggled, which I already mentioned, is most likely common industry standard.

Comment: Also, this guy already did something similar... I just want something I can put together faster and more reliably: https://www.swharden.com/wp/2016-09-19-hacking-a-cheap-ammeter-voltmeter-to-provide-a-bluetooth-pc-interface/

Comment: The unit pictured is just a shunt with an LCD, is there a reason you've chosen to decode the LCD output instead of directly reading the measured current? ...Or what about just using a shunt by itself?

Comment: @mrdabbleswithpotion - Um, you asked a question. I asked you a question so that I may better understand the context of your needs. But instead of answering me, you told me that I'm spouting "non-sense". That doesn't encourage me to answer your question.

Comment: "Since I'm interfacing it through USB to my PC" - how exactly do you envision the conversion of 11 channels at 1 kHz toggling rate into "USB"?

Comment: That project you link to, is doing exactly what you want. I am unsure of what you mean by more reliably. And faster than being spoon fed a project with code? That project is twice what you need since it uses a Bluetooth module and reads two displays instead of one.

Comment: @Passerby: I wanted to do away with the Bluetooth, actually.

Comment: @AliChen: By using a development board, like I already conceded with, if you would read the comments?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

*Figure 1. A typical 4-digit common cathode 7-segment display with decimal points. Source: [7-segment display basics](http://lednique.com/display-technology/7-segment-display-basics/).*

*If* the display is multiplexed as shown above then you could conceivably do what you are thinking.

- Monitor each of the strobe lines, 1s, 10s and 100s, in your case.
- When that line switches low (assuming you are monitoring at the common cathode, you wait a moment and then read lines a to g.
- You decode these by performing a 7-segment to decimal lookup.
- You then have the option of transmitting these as a byte per digit or combining these into one 8-bit value (if the meter maximum is < 255) or a 16-bit value which will be more than enough for '999'.

The problems:

1. You have given no clue what the operating voltage of the meter is. It may not be compatible with any micro that you wish to use.
2. The display would have to share a common ground with the micro. This may not be possible but, again, you haven't provided a schematic so we don't know.
3. The multiplexed line voltages may not comply with the logic levels of your micro so it won't reliably be able to read high and low from the LEDs.
4. The display driver will have current limiting. If there is one green LED per segment on your display then the forward voltage drop across that segment will be about 2 V. Where will the rest of the voltage be dropped? On the anode feed or the cathode feed or both? Again this will affect the voltage levels.

[image]

*Figure 2. Sneak-paths in multiplexed displays. Source: [Failure modes for LEDs](http://lednique.com/technology-basics/failure-modes-leds/).*

5. In Figure 2 above S2 and S6 are closed and D7 (shown in red) is lit. Meanwhile L5, 6 and 8 are forward biased (shown in grey) and raise the voltage on the S4, 5 and 7 lines. (The multiplexed display relies on the remainder of the LEDs, shown in yellow, don’t break down due to the reverse voltage.) These stray voltages may also interfere with your scheme.
6. You would have to replicate this scheme for each display. You couldn't, for example common all the 'a' segments as the displays are running asynchronously - apart from any short circuits and interference between them.
7. You would be sharing USB ground with a power circuit. Any errors or faults may destroy the host device (your laptop?).

You would be far better to read the voltages directly from the shunts, amplify them as required and feed into the micro analog inputs.

The illustrations and linked articles are [mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/73158/transistor).

Comment: Regarding the "problem #1", all these meter panel use on-board LDO to 3.3V (blue displays might use 5V rail). But all other concerns about variable voltage levels might require some threshold care on GPIO side, +1.

Comment: Also, the OP seems to think that he can magically "simply sample these 12 pins" with some magic "USB to PC" device. The solution you give requires certain hardware effort.

Comment: 2 is also not an issue with these.

Comment: @Passerby: If they are powered by the two wires shown we still have no idea what potential is on the wires. The black may not be grounded. That was my point 2.

Comment: @Transistor: You're just misleading us now... This is an \$n\$ x \$m\$ matrix, where the WORD controlling \$n\$ also has bit length n and the WORD controlling \$m\$ also has bit length m, and an \$n\$ x \$m\$ matrix is DOES NOT use multiplexing.

Comment: @Transistor: Multiplexing a matrix is USUALLY used with an \$n\$ x \$2^m\$ matrix, where the WORD controlling n also has bit length n and the adjacent side is q, controlled by \$m = \log_2 q\$ bits. The q side "multiplexes" each column or row with each decoding of each binary number. So less bits, m, are needed for the adjacent sides.

Comment: @Transistor: I know what a Multiplexer (coming from Computing Science) is and I have also programmed with an LED matrix that is multiplexed in a micro-controller development board a decade ago for the supplemental course I took by my own back in the University. Don't muddle, confuse and lie to us.

Comment: Actually I can "simply sample these 12 pins". I simply have to determine the HI and LO voltage and then use a level-shifter. How do I know what voltage level are HI and LO?? Some level shifter will can already be used. Say an op-amp whose rail voltage is equal the rail of the voltmeter, used in open loop, with the \$V_{in}\$ having a forward biased diode, for good measure, to clip any non-absolute zero LOs.

Comment: @Passerby: I agree. Transistor is just filling it up so the list can go  on longer.

Comment: "*Don't muddle, confuse and **lie** to us.*" Conversation ended.

Comment: @Transistor: There could be other ways to do multiplexing on a Seven Segment Display, but what you just described above is NOT multiplexing. If the display is doing it as you described above, then it is not a Seven Segment Display and the whole discussion is for naught.

Comment: Oh, but, I've never lied.

Comment: About the level-shifter comment 4 comments above this one, I have a correction. This op-amp setup only works when the rail is the level of the IO of the board. The voltmeter is about 3.5V-30V in supply range (if I recall correctly), so a board with 30V HI is unlikely. Plus, it doesn't really determine the HI and LO of the LED display. However, if we feed the op-amp's output to a level shifter that takes as input about 30V HI and can level shift down to the the board's IO, then it works for all cases. But, the HI and LO of the LED display is still not determined.

Comment: Or you can simply take a level shifter with input of 3.5V max to the needed board IO. As 3.5V is the highest HI the voltmeter IC can be made to work with the LED display, if one expects the voltmeter to work down to 3.5V supply. Unless the LED display's HI ramps up with the supply voltage, but I don't think it's like that.